# Firmware upgrade issue with SIM7600

Tags: microcontroller, gsm, at-command

I've a batch of SIM7600CEs on which a bunch of SSL commands aren't working, and this led me to the prospect of upgrading the modem's firmware.
I've installed the drivers, but at exactly 1.25% QDL v1.41 stops the process, the modem turns off doesn't turn back ON again. I get the error:

```
2023-06-15 14:24:26: Phone Call State: CM_{ CALL_STATE_IDLE
2023-06-15} 14:24:26: Phone System Mode State: SYS_{ SYS_MODE_NO_SRV
2023-06-15} 14:24:26: FTM Mode: OFF  
2023-06-15 14:24:29: Waiting switch To Download Mode...  
2023-06-15 14:24:33: Connecting Sahara Server 1 times....  
2023-06-15 14:24:33: saharaHandle=0x0498, Version:2  
2023-06-15 14:24:34: Version: 2, MSMId: 0,SN: 0.  
2023-06-15 14:24:34: Waiting Sahara_{ FlashProgrammer...
2023-06-15} 14:24:37: QMSL_{ DownloadAgent::Step2} (Downloading Software Image Files)  
2023-06-15 14:24:37: Sending HELLO to flash programmer, 1  
2023-06-15 14:24:37: HELLO command succeeded, block size 1024, window size 2  
2023-06-15 14:24:37: Set Security Mode, bUseTrusted = 1  
2023-06-15 14:24:37: Sending Partition Table: C:UserspcDesktopBackupSIM7600SIM7600_{ Firmware_Upgrade-master} (Firmware and Tool)LE20B04SIM7600M22partition.mbn, bOverride=0  
2023-06-15 14:24:37: Downloading 0:SBL  
2023-06-15 14:24:37: Downloading sbl1.mbn...  
2023-06-15 14:24:38: Downloaded C:UserspcDesktopBackupSIM7600SIM7600_{ Firmware_Upgrade-master} (Firmware and Tool)LE20B04SIM7600M22sbl1.mbn : 1187ms  
2023-06-15 14:24:38: Downloading 0:TZ  
2023-06-15 14:24:38: Downloading tz.mbn...  
2023-06-15 14:24:41: Downloaded C:UserspcDesktopBackupSIM7600SIM7600_{ Firmware_Upgrade-master} (Firmware and Tool)LE20B04SIM7600M22tz.mbn : 2609ms  
2023-06-15 14:24:41: Downloading 0:RPM  
2023-06-15 14:24:41: Downloading rpm.mbn...  
2023-06-15 14:24:41: Downloaded C:UserspcDesktopBackupSIM7600SIM7600_{ Firmware_Upgrade-master} (Firmware and Tool)LE20B04SIM7600M22rpm.mbn : 891ms  
2023-06-15 14:24:41: Downloading 0:aboot  
2023-06-15 14:24:41: Downloading appsboot_{ fastboot_9x07.mbn...
2023-06-15} 14:24:44: Downloaded C:UserspcDesktopBackupSIM7600SIM7500_{ SIM7600_QDL} V1.41 Only for Updateappsboot_{ fastboot_9x07.mbn} : 2187ms  
2023-06-15 14:24:44: SB3 Download Finished. Success = YES  
2023-06-15 14:24:44: CP Download Success!  
2023-06-15 14:24:44: waiting for dut,long time please repower dut...
```

Now if I disconnect the modem, and turn it back ON, it's no longer displayed as a bunch of peripherals in the device manager. Instead, there's only one entry marked "Android". There was a warning sign icon next to this, but this went away when I installed the android drivers.
I am able to retry the upgrade process, if I short the BOOTCFG jumper on my board. But then again the upload fails at 1.25%.
Using a different version of QDL (v1.52) led to the process getting stopped at 0.85%.
Tried uploading the firmware using SB3 option in QPST. The process completed in just 11 seconds, and I don't get any errors, but apparently the firmware isn't getting loaded correctly. Behind the scenes, it's stopping exactly the way that it did with QDL.

If someone can give me a rough overview of the nature of the firmware, different tools used to upgrade it and what happens during the upgrade process.

All help is appreciated.

Tried different firmware version

Answer (score 0):

QDL at some point in time tries to reboot the modem, but due to the `boot_cfg0` jumper, the modem reboots in mode 9008. After the message `waiting for dut, long time please repower dut...` appears, remove the jumper and reboot the modem. After rebooting the modem with the `boot_cfg0` jumper removed, QDL will see it and continue working.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up figuring it out. But there was an extra step. After it boots up again, it pops up as an adb device, and I had to install the drivers.